# Incorporate an unmanaged EXE as resource in a managed C# code

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unmanaged

I have a given code written in unmanaged C++ that I added as a resource in a C# program.

When trying to load the unmanaged EXE using `Assembly.Load`, I get a `BadImageFormatException` whose InnerException says that "the IL Format is incorrect" (obviously).

How can I make this work?

I know that using the code as a DLL would be better, but for some reason, the dll call does not behave the same way as when I run the unmanaged exe with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.

And I don't want to have two separates EXE files. Any idea?

---

**EDIT:** OK, I no longer need to do that. My dll behaved a different way because I was using it in a different context (winform instead of console); therefore the function causing the problem, `SetThreadDesktop`, couldn't work as expected. Gonna close post now, thanks for all those who answered.

Comment: What are you trying to use this unmanaged executable? Run it? You'd have to save the embedded EXE, maybe to the %TEMP% path, and use `Process.Start` to get it going. Then use `WaitForExit`, and delete the EXE to clean up.

Comment: That's a good idea indeed, but I'd rather have this work without generating the embedded EXE

Comment: You should be able to compile the C++ into a mixed-mode assembly, using the C++/CLI compiler, and link it with your C# code into a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load an unmanaged exe/dll with `Assembly.Load()`, it works only with managed ones. if you need to PInvoke on that unmanaged file, and the reason you want a single exe is just deploy, you can pack it as an embedded resource (as you currently did ) and unpack on the target machine in a file, and use it as usual.

Comment: Okay, but maybe someone can give me a hint on making this work without Assembly.Load

Comment: @GianT971 I supposed you already try the game before trying to pack in a single exe. Follow some PInvoke tutorial as suggested by Alexei (+1)

Comment: Will take a look at this, will give feedback tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

If you have unmanaged DLL as resource - basic steps:

- [Save resource to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864140/write-file-from-assembly-resource-stream-to-disk) at run-time
- use LoadLibrary (Win32 call to [LoadLibrary using PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/LoadLibrary.html))
- either use methods from this library by calling methods [annotated for PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx), or [manually via GetProcAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754264/c-sharp-getprocaddress-returns-zero).

Comment: What do you mean by "Save resource to disk at run-time"? How do I do that?*

Comment: We have search engine for it :) - http://www.bing.com/search?q=Save+resource+to+disk+at+run-time , but here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864140/write-file-from-assembly-resource-stream-to-disk

Comment: Ok and you think that this way the result could be different as just importing the dll to the project?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean "different" - you can't "import" native DLL to managed project.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov As spotted by Ramhound, it is possible to use dllimport, and that's what I was doing, thus the "different"

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach, that could be automated, is using the so-called "assembly weaving" 
[Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) - https://github.com/Fody/Costura - is the one of the 'weavers'. The embedding process (with tests automation) for incorporating unmanaged resources and transparently loading them at runtime without much of effort -

`Install-Package Fody.Costura`

Then all of embedding, unpacking, assembly locating and loading is automated by default, and controlled by including 'FodyWeavers.xml' config, added to your project.

> `<Costura>
>       <Unmanaged32Assemblies>
>           Foo32
>           Bar32
>       </Unmanaged32Assemblies>
>       <Unmanaged64Assemblies>
>           Foo64
>           Bar64
>       </Unmanaged64Assemblies>
>   </Costura>`

The concept behind approach, is static `<Module>` class loader, that is binary changed by Fody project tasks, after your project assembly was successfully built. Internally Mono.Cecil is used for the static `'<Module>'` loader injection that unpacks resources automatically, saves them to temporary directory, telling to load dll's from that location, etc. at assembly load event.