# Load dynamic library and use functions inside the library

Tags: c#, dynamic-library

In C#, I am using an external dll, using loadLibrary, like this:

```
public class Utilities
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet= CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string librayName);
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet= CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(intPtr hwnd, string procedureName);

    public static LoadAssembliesAndMethods() {
        string mainPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string path = Path.Combine(mainPath, "MyAssembly.dll");

        IntPtr ptr = LoadLibrary(path);

        // What to do next in order to get all the list of functions/methods/class in the library and use them?

    }
```

The dll has no signature of Assembly (it's a 3rd party), so I cannot do

```
Assebly.LoadFile(path);
```

I need to get all of the functions/methods/class of the dll, and use some of them, using C#.

How can I do that.

Comment: what kind of dll library do you want to load?

Comment: `LoadLibrary` then `GetProcAddress(hLibrary, functionName)` returns address (`IntPtr`) of the desired function

Comment: I don't know if the desire function is inside a static class or just a function. I don't have the source of the 3rd party library. I need to check the list of the classes, and list of methods, and use then use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list all methods inside a unmanaged dll this link help you:

[C# get the list of unmanaged C dll exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249566/c-sharp-get-the-list-of-unmanaged-c-dll-exports)

Update:

```
IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(Handle,functionName);
YourFunctionDelegate function = 
Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcaddr,typeof(YourFunctionDelegate )) 
as YourFunctionDelegate ;
function.Invoke(pass here your parameters);
```

you need to create delegates at coding or using DynamicModules for creating delegates at runtime

Comment: Thank you.

That's help.
I see function "AFunc" - How can I call that function?
Thanks.

Comment: @Eitan check update, use Delegate.CreateDelegate for creating delegate at runtime

Comment: after doing: IntPtr ptr = LoadLibrary(path) (as my code); & IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(Handle,functionName);  I get funcaddr=0x00000000, and not a valid address (Even I see that the function name is in the list (as the link you gave: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249566/c-sharp-get-the-list-of-unmanaged-c-dll-exports)

Comment: OK. found the mistake: as i see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754264/c-sharp-getprocaddress-returns-zero, I see I need to change in the decorator of GetProcAddress: CharSet = CharSet.Ansi

Comment: Also, can you give me, please an example for: GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate>(IntPtr)

Comment: @Eitan you need to create delegate yourself or create it at Runtime based on parameters that you read, the hardest part of your work is to create delegate and pass to GetDelegateForFunctionPointer

Answer (score 1):

There is no common way to get the export list of a unmanaged library programatically.

See [Is there a way to find all the functions exposed by a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437432/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-functions-exposed-by-a-dll) for more info